# Saving a views sql query

Tags: views, nodes, database

I am using Drupal 6, and Views 2.0; I need to create a node where one of the fields is a filterable view. I then need to store the final SQL query of the view in the database.

How would I add the block view to a node creation page?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. You are describing the basic operation of the Views module. Watch the video series [Taming the Beast](http://%20http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) to get a handle on how to use views.

Comment: The OP said, "I need to create a node where one of the fields is a filterable view." It doesn't seem that is one of the basic operations of the Views module.

Comment: yes, basically on node/create I would like for the user to "filter" a specified view and when clicking save I would like to store the views sql query. Have you seen this being done before? I could not find any reference to anyhting like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to solve this issue, so I did a little bit of a work around.

What I did was built a content type where the user could specify what data he/she needed by use of a form and fields.

I then took the user input and built a dynamic sql query to output the required data.

Its a pretty dirty way of doing it... but until I find another solution, I'll have to use it.